# How can I use the similar VBA code in VB.NET?

Tags: json, vb.net, http, request, xmlhttprequest

I have this code which makes an http request and returns the result in VBA (Excel).
Does anyone know how to do similar in VB.NET?

```vb
Sub GetRequest()

    MYURL = "xxx"
    Accesstoken = "xxx"

    'Send Request and get JSON Response
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & AccessToken
    xmlhttp.Send
    JsonResponse = xmlhttp.responseText
    Debug.Print xmlhttp.responseText
    
    'Parse JSON
    Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJSON(JsonResponse)
    Debug.Print xmlhttp.responseText

    Set xmlhttp = Nothing


End Sub
```

I'm new to VB.NET and mainly only use Excel VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send/receive HTTP requests/responses, typically you would use the HttpClient class ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient)). Specifically in this case you would:

1. Call the GetAsync method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync)) to submit the request
2. Check the response's StatusCode ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage)) to verify that a successful response was returned (presumably an OK - 200 status)
3. If a successful response was returned, get the response's Content ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent))

Here is a function (untested) that should get you going in the right direction:

```vb
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Text
'...
Private Async Function SendGet(url As String) As Task(Of String)
    Dim body = String.Empty
    Using client = New HttpClient
        Dim response = Await client.GetAsync(url)

        If (response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK) Then
            body = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        End If
    End Using
    Return body
End Function
```